# NumberBox not showing actual value in WinUI 3

Tags: windows, winui-3

A number box in my WinUI 3 application is displaying the float value 5.94 as "5.9399999995". This number box is bound to a float property of a view model. There are other number boxes that are bound to different instances of the same view model, and the others display their float values fine (fine meaning showing 2 decimal digits, defined by the number formatter bound to all these number boxes).

The number box Xaml definition:

```
<NumberBox
  Value="{x:Bind Path=MainVM.ViewModel[5].SomeNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
  />
```

As said before, each of these number boxes has a number formatter attached that limits the decimal digits to 2 digits, but that still doesn't explain why 5.94 is being displayed not as 5.94.

Comment: The Type of NumberBox.Value property is Double and so the float value is casted to double. `(double)5.94f` produces 5.940000057220459.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Binary floating point math is like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

But in this case, you can implement a custom [number formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.numberbox.numberformatter), for example like this:

```
public class DoubleFormatter : INumberFormatter2, INumberParser
{
    public virtual string Format { get; set; } = "{0:F2}"; // by default we use this but you can change it in the XAML declaration
    public virtual string FormatDouble(double value) => string.Format(Format, value);
    public virtual double? ParseDouble(string text) => double.TryParse(text, out var dbl) ? dbl : null;

    // we only support doubles
    public string FormatInt(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public string FormatUInt(ulong value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public long? ParseInt(string text) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public ulong? ParseUInt(string text) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Note: it's not documented AFAIK but an [INumberFormatter2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.numberformatting.inumberformatter2) must also implement [INumberParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.numberformatting.inumberparser) otherwise you get "invalid argument" of more exotic cryptic errors...

Sample XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:DoubleFormatter x:Key="df" /> <!-- change Format here -->
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <NumberBox NumberFormatter="{StaticResource df}" Value="{x:Bind MyFloatValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, this is a problem with the `NumberFormatter`. Can you try this code?

```cs
namespace NumberBoxExample;

// Customize the return values if you need to.
public class CustomIncrementNumberRounder : INumberRounder
{
    public double RoundDouble(double value) => value;

    public int RoundInt32(int value) => value;

    public long RoundInt64(long value) => value;

    public float RoundSingle(float value) => value;

    public uint RoundUInt32(uint value) => value;

    public ulong RoundUInt64(ulong value) => value;
}
```

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="NumberBoxExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:f="using:Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting"
    xmlns:local="using:NumberBoxExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <f:DecimalFormatter
        x:Key="DecimalFormatter"
        FractionDigits="2"
        NumberRounder="{StaticResource CustomIncrementNumberRounder}" />
</Page.Resources>

<NumberBox NumberFormatter="{StaticResource DecimalFormatter}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I have some more info now so I'm going to write up a more in-depth question tomorrow. Thank you for the suggestion.